# How to disable calculating with nans while pandas resample().mean() and resample().sum()?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, mean, resampling

I need to calculate the annual mean from monthly data. If there is a nan value in my monthly data, I want the whole year to be nan as well.

This is my code so far:

```
station_data = pd.read_csv(station_data_files[0], sep=';', header=0)
station_data = station_data.replace(-999, np.nan)
station_data = station_data.set_index("MESS_DATUM_BEGINN") # it is a row with time dates

station_data_anual = pd.DataFrame()
station_data_anual["Y_TT"] = station_data["MO_TT"].resample("A").mean()
station_data_anual["Y_RR"] = station_data["MO_RR"].resample("A").sum()
```

The problem is, that it ignores the nans. Which means e.g. that `station_data_anual["Y_RR"]` values are to low. For years in which I have only nans as monthly values, it returns 0.

Note: There are some questions similar to mine, but they didn't help me.
Note: Python

some clarifications:

Input Data:

```
station_data
Out[235]: 
                   STATIONS_ID MESS_DATUM_ENDE  QN_4  ...  MO_RR  MX_RS  eor
MESS_DATUM_BEGINN                                     ...                   
1981-01-01               403.0      1981-01-31  10.0  ...   51.5   10.0  eor
1981-02-01               403.0      1981-02-28  10.0  ...   23.8    5.4  eor
1981-03-01               403.0      1981-03-31  10.0  ...  116.5   28.0  eor
1981-04-01               403.0      1981-04-30  10.0  ...   24.1    9.5  eor
1981-05-01               403.0      1981-05-31  10.0  ...   29.4    8.4  eor
                       ...             ...   ...  ...    ...    ...  ...
2010-08-01               403.0      2010-08-31  10.0  ...    NaN   29.1  eor
2010-09-01               403.0      2010-09-30  10.0  ...    NaN   29.8  eor
2010-10-01               403.0      2010-10-31  10.0  ...    NaN    5.5  eor
2010-11-01               403.0      2010-11-30  10.0  ...    NaN   17.5  eor
2010-12-01               403.0      2010-12-31  10.0  ...    NaN    8.2  eor

[360 rows x 16 columns]
```

have a closer look:

```
station_data["MO_RR"][276:288]
Out[242]: 
MESS_DATUM_BEGINN
2004-01-01    66.3
2004-02-01     NaN
2004-03-01     NaN
2004-04-01     NaN
2004-05-01     NaN
2004-06-01     NaN
2004-07-01     NaN
2004-08-01     NaN
2004-09-01     NaN
2004-10-01     NaN
2004-11-01     NaN
2004-12-01     NaN
Name: MO_RR, dtype: float64
```

Output Data:

```
station_data_anual
Out[238]: 
                        Y_TT   Y_RR
MESS_DATUM_BEGINN                  
...
2003-12-31          9.866667  430.5
2004-12-31          9.620833   66.3
2005-12-31          9.665833    0.0
2006-12-31         10.158333    0.0
2007-12-31         10.555000    0.0
2008-12-31         10.361667    0.0
2009-12-31          9.587500    0.0
2010-12-31          8.207500    0.0
```

my result has to look like:

```
                        Y_TT       Y_TX      Y_TN   Y_RR
MESS_DATUM_BEGINN                                       
... 
                        Y_TT   Y_RR
MESS_DATUM_BEGINN                  
...
2003-12-31          9.866667  430.5
2004-12-31          9.620833    nan    # getting nan instead of 66.3 is especially important
2005-12-31          9.665833    nan
2006-12-31         10.158333    nan
2007-12-31         10.555000    nan
2008-12-31         10.361667    nan
2009-12-31          9.587500    nan
2010-12-31          8.207500    nan
```

Comment: By default `skipna` is `True` when doing `mean()` in pandas. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

Comment: @moys thank you for your answer, but "station_data_anual["Y_TT"] = station_data["MO_TT"].resample("A").mean(skipna=True)" returns: "UnsupportedFunctionCall: numpy operations are not valid with resample. Use .resample(...).mean() instead"

Comment: Can you post the input data & expected output data (as text)? That would make it much easier to look for issues & provide you a solution.

Comment: @moys oky, but it is a little bit big

Comment: @moys oky I posted the input data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used sampling and there might be better solutions out there which could simply ignore the "group" based on "condition". But a very simple solution could be to use a custom mean function after `resample`.

```py
def very_mean(array_like):
    if any(pd.isnull(array_like)):
        return np.nan
    else:
        return array_like.mean()

station_data_anual["Y_TT"] = station_data["MO_TT"].resample("A").apply(very_mean)
```

Comment: Thank you. What shall I put in for "array"? I put in "station_data" for "array". But when I do so, the function returns just nans.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to work. And it is also nice to know know how to build a funktion. I am not that atvanced. I still have to learn how to build funktions. :) I am happy now!

Comment: This does work, but for some reason it's extremely slow. In fact it's considerably slower to do `.apply(lambda x: x.sum())` than it is to do `.sum()` ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to remove the nan values first using?

```
station_data_anual = pd.DataFrame()
station_data_anual["Y_TT"] = station_data["MO_TT"].dropna().resample("A").mean()
station_data_anual["Y_RR"] = station_data["MO_RR"].dropna().resample("A").sum()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For "MO_RR" in the year 2004 it still returns "66.3". For the years with only nan values it returns nan.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that NaN values are not included in the mean, considering the following experiment:

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("2022","2023",periods=12))
df_['a'] = np.ones(12)
df_.iloc[1]['a'] = np.NaN
df_.resample("2M").mean()
```

All of the averaged 2 month periods still have 1.0 as the mean value in the output of the mean() calculation above:

```
              a
2022-01-31  1.0
2022-03-31  1.0
2022-05-31  1.0
2022-07-31  1.0
2022-09-30  1.0
2022-11-30  1.0
2023-01-31  1.0
```